# Google Maps Not Centering and Zooming On Markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-markers

All of my markers are coming from an AJAX call and are accurately placed on the map. However, the initial view is fully zoomed out, along the equator, in North America.

I know the solution lays somewhere with `bounds.extend` and `map.fitBounds` but apparently I'm doing it wrong.

I've always had an issue with this, so hopefully someone can help elevate this thorn in my side:

```
var map;
var markers = [];
var home_marker;

function initialize() {

    // Display a map on the page
    if ( document.contains(document.getElementById("map_canvas")) ) {

        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.4222, -123.3657)
        });

        // a new Info Window is created
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        // Event that closes the InfoWindow with a click on the map
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.close();
        });

        // Add Home Marker
        home_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(user_address_lat, user_address_lng),
            map: map,
            icon: '/images/map-icon-your-home.png'
        });

    }

}

function displayMarkers( properties ) {

    // this variable sets the map bounds and zoom level according to markers position
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // For loop that runs through the info on markersData making it possible to createMarker function to create the markers
    for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++){

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(properties[i]['latitude'], properties[i]['longitude']);
        var price_current = properties[i]['price_current'];
        var bedrooms = properties[i]['bedrooms'];
        var total_baths = properties[i]['total_baths'];
        var listing_id = properties[i]['listing_id'];

        createMarker( latlng, price_current, bedrooms, total_baths, matrix_unique_ID );

        // Marker’s Lat. and Lng. values are added to bounds variable
        bounds.extend(latlng);

    }

    // Finally the bounds variable is used to set the map bounds
    // with API’s fitBounds() function
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function createMarker( latlng, price, bedrooms, bathrooms, matrix_id ) {

    var formatted_price = accounting.formatMoney(price, '$', 0);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng,
        icon: '/images/map-icon.png'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

        // Variable to define the HTML content to be inserted in the infowindow
        var iwContent = '<div class="row"><div class="small-12 columns"><img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/properties/'+listing_id+'/image-'+matrix_id+'-1.jpg"></div></div>' +
                        '<div class="row"><div class="small-12 columns"><p class="price-current text-center">'+formatted_price+'</p></div></div><hr>' +
                        '<div class="row"><div class="small-6 columns"><p class="bedrooms"><span class="fw-semi-bold">Beds:</span> '+bedrooms+'</p></div>' +
                        '<div class="small-6 columns"><p class="total-baths"><span class="fw-semi-bold">Baths:</span> '+bathrooms+'</p></div></div>';

        // including content to the infowindow
        infoWindow.setContent(iwContent);

        // opening the infowindow in the current map and at the current marker location
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);

    });

}

// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}

// Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearMarkers() {
    setMapOnAll(null);
}

// Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
function deleteMarkers() {
    clearMarkers();
    markers = [];
}
```

Comment: Don't down vote this question if you have nothing to add. I'm searched for a solution and they aren't working.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Um... that's literally my entire code. It's beyond minimal, it's complete, it's tested and perfectly readable. Go troll somewhere else.

Comment: No data/HTML/CSS?  How does it display markers?  There is no call to `DisplayMarkers`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new Part to your script or make a new one, and code it specificly to change zoom in camera ammount and, add ui button for it.

Comment: ...what? Sorry, that isn't at all helpful. The solution lays with `bounds.extend();` and `map.fitBounds();`